# Windows Phone 8.1/10 Crash Dumps

Tags: crash, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile, crash-dumps

An app I am testing ceases to boot-up and crashes shortly after app splash screen. I have noticed an option to save crash dumps via developer section on Windows Phone 8.1 and 10. These crash dumps are supposedly stored in Documents (phone storage or SD card)... but it never appears there?

Any idea why no crash dumps are being saved?

Comment: how long have you waited? It sometimes takes some time to create the full dump. Also try to connect the phone again to the PC and look again into this folder

Comment: were you now able to get the dump?